# jQuery parsing Array Json

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, highcharts

This is my Json

```
[{"name":"Male","data":[10,34,30]},{"name":"Female","data":[20,22,15]},{"name":"Male","data":[22,21,21]},{"name":"Female","data":[13,20,31]}]
```

and then push it to create chart , am doing some thing wrong ,here my code:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
     <html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Highcharts Example</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"  type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.3.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">



          /*  var items = [{
                "name": "Male",
                "data": [10, 34, 30]
            }, {
                "name": "Female",
                "data": [20, 22, 15]

            }];*/

                var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //define the options
            var options = {
                chart: {
                    renderTo: 'container',
                    type: 'bar'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
                },
                subtitle: {
                    text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Age 20-24', 'Age 25-30', 'Age 30-40'],
                    title: {
                        text: null
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Population (millions)',
                        align: 'high'
                    },
                    labels: {
                        overflow: 'justify'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '' +
                            this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + ' millions';
                    }
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    layout: 'vertical',
                    align: 'right',
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    x: -100,
                    y: 100,
                    floating: true,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                    shadow: true
                },
                credits: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{

                }]
            };


            //Calls the JSON
            jQuery.getJSON("XSportWithAgegroup",
                            null, function (items) {
                                //Creates the new series as stated in the documentation
                                //http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series
                                var series = {

                                    name: 'Browser Share',
                                    data: []
                                };
                                jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    //Get the items from the JSON and add then
                                    //to the data array of the series



                                        series.data.push({
                                            name: item.name,
                                            y: item.data[0],
                                        })

                                });
                                options.series.push(series);
                                //Create the chart
                                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                                chart.render();
                            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

     <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
```

Here my methoed to convert query result to json:

```
 public JsonResult XSportWithAgegroup() { 

       var series = (from m in db.Agegroup
                     where m.Gender == "Male" || m.Gender == "Female"
                     select new
                     {
                         name = m.Gender,
                         data = new List<double> { m.Age20To24, m.Age25To30, m.Age30To40 }
                     }).ToArray();

       return Json(series, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

I think my problem is with the jQuery
the demo for the chart is :http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

**Update :**

my json:

```
   [{"name":"Male","data":[10,34,30]},{"name":"Female","data":[20,22,15]}]
```

My JQuery  :

```
    //Calls the JSON
            jQuery.getJSON("XDiesesWithAgegroup",
                            null, function (items) {
                                //Creates the new series as stated in the documentation
                                //http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#series
                                var series = { name: 'll', data: [] };




                                jQuery.each(items, function (itemNo, item) {
                                    //Get the items from the JSON and add then
                                    //to the data array of the series


                                    for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
                                        series.data.push({
                                            name: item.name,
                                            y: item.data[i],
                                        });


                                  }//end for

                                });

                                options.series.push(series);

                                //Create the chart
                                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                                chart.render();

                            });
```

here how the chart look like Now:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER6BZ.png

Comment: Did you tried adding chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); outside jQuery.getJSON block, I face similar issue but got that work done by creating chart at bottom of series update code but inside document.reaydy

Comment: yah some time coz of that. but in my case coz of jquery push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have no property `Gender` in your JSON array, just `name`. You can either change your JSON data to use `Gender` instead of `name` or change your code the other way round

```
series.data.push({
    name: item.name,
    y: item.data[i],
});
```

There are several points with the code you posted. All of them show up, when you look into the console. I copied the code into [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEsyz/1/)  and together with [Highcharts - How To Use](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use), I modified it a bit

`y: item.data[i],`: `i` not defined. I took just the first element

```
series.data.push({
    name: item.Gender,
    y: item.data[0],
})
```

`options` not defined and no target for the chart

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var options = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container' },
    series: []
};
```

I think the main point is, you must provide a target for the chart to render.

**Update**:

Comparing your data with the link you provided, I just dropped the loop and assigned your JSON data directly to `series`. Combining with a bar type, the chart starts looking similar.

```
var options = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'bar' },
    series: items
};
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEsyz/3/)

**Update 2**:

So you have only two entries, `Male` and `Female`, with three subentries each. The Y-Axis is labelled `Age 20-24`, `Age 25-30` and `Age 30-40`.

```
var options = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'bar' },
    xAxis: {
                categories: ['Age 20-24', 'Age 25-30', 'Age 30-40'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
    series: items
};
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dEsyz/4/)

**Update 3**:

```
var options = {
    chart: { renderTo: 'container', type: 'bar' },
    xAxis: {
                categories: ['Age 20-24', 'Age 25-30', 'Age 30-40'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
    series: null
};

jQuery.getJSON("XDiesesWithAgegroup", function (items) {
    options.series = items;

    //Create the chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: you what you said make is right ,I changed but still i can not see the chart.

Comment: Please check my code again , i were using the wrong chart type ,now at least getting the chart but not as the same format as demo i provided.

Comment: No,, Oky this my mistake i could not explain my problem well ..I put the var item only to test my Query and to  know how my JSON look like ..but actually I am getting my JSON from method XSportWithAgegroup()...u can review the Q again..sorry.. know getting chart but not with the proper format..

Comment: @user1476956 Still guessing, see Update 2 and JSFiddle. If this still doesn't fit, try explaining every single piece: vertical axis, horizontal axis, real life JSON layout, and so on ... you might even try experimenting with JSFiddle yourself.

Comment: I don't use  series: items i will use my JQuery to push the json data as  I code. i think i have some thing wrong while pushing the element of the array .

Comment: @user1476956 Yes, I already got that. I keep using that until I find out, how the graph should look like. You do have one dimension `Male/Female` and another dimension `Age 20-24/25-30/30-40`, right? What goes on the vertical axis `Male...` or `Age...`?

Comment: yes as you have in JSFiddle tht is exactly what I want.. ..BUT ...i need the same result  using my Jquery coz i am getting the json from code behind ..and i get the json in proper format as i said in the question.. that why i think when i push the data some thing going wrong..

Comment: and yes my categories should be 'Age 20-24', 'Age 25-30', 'Age 30-40' Right . I will update it

Comment: vertical axis  going Male/female exactly the same what you have in JSFiddle

Comment: @user1476956 Ok, so the chart looks right, only the series data must be modified? What are the values, from top to bottom, you expect in the chart?

Comment: yes I have update the jquery (see the updata) to have loop for data[i] and I post link for the chart how dose it look now. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: @user1476956 This is how the chart looks now. And how do you want it?

Comment: values from top to bottom should by the way u have it in JSFiddle.I really want to learn how to handel this situation coz am going to deal with many charts which have diff format to push the data.

Comment: @user1476956 But then you can just assign the `items` to `options.series` as I already suggested. Please see update.

Comment: let say first age group "Age 20-24" should have data[0] for female=20 and male=12 and so on i used for loop but stil go wrong.

Comment: @user1476956 If your JSON is `[{"name":"Male","data":[10,34,30]},{"name":"Female","data":[20,22,15]}]`, then you don't need to modify it. Please see my latest update.

Comment: OMG ..ThanK You Very Much..I cant believe ..how that work??!! I just delete all stff in the JQuery and did what u did ...!! is that mean whenever my format of the Json that i get it from code-behind is  in the right way  I just have to pass to Jquery the way u did??

Comment: @user1476956 Yes, that's just it. If the data is already properly formatted, then you can just pass it on.

Comment: okay ..Now i understand I suffer for one week doing this ...Thank You very much for the effort.... One last question i get every thing in the chart except the (description square) , i mean the one which describe what each color for red for female .. blue for male ?

Comment: @user1476956 That should be shown automatically. See the last JSFiddle. I also tried your options and it shows there as well. Maybe you changed some option, which suppresses the legend.

Comment: oky  Now work good.. i know why i delete the  chart.render();....u know why that happen?